# Swagger-autogen in Express - description and schema from response appears in parameters

Tags: swagger, swagger-autogen

In Express app, I've created swagger autogen tags.

In this place this setup does not work, because *description* and *schema* fields from response are in parameters in output. I'm using "swagger-autogen": "2.23.1". This error appears in some controllers, in other not.
I can delete #swagger.responses[200] part, but then there is no body in file.

```js
export const getDiary = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  /* 
    #swagger.tags = ['Diary']
    #swagger.description = 'Get all Diary entries'
    #swagger.parameters['date'] = {
      in: 'query',
      description: 'Date of diary entry',
      required: false,
    }
    #swagger.responses[200] = {
      description: 'Diary entries successfully obtained',
      schema: { $ref: '#/definitions/DiaryResponse'}
    }
  */

  let { date } = req.query;

  const mappedRows = date
    ? await DiaryService.getAllDiaryEntriesByDate(date as string)
    : await DiaryService.getAllDiaryEntries();

  let response: HttpResponse<Diary[]> = {
    data: mappedRows,
    length: mappedRows.length,
  };

  return res.status(RESPONSE_CODES.OK).send(response);
};
```

generated swagger

```json
    "/api/diary/": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Diary"
        ],
        "description": "Get all Diary entries",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "date",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "Date of diary entry",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "description", // this should not be here
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "schema", // this should not be here
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add.

```
#swagger.auto = false
```

Then description and schema from responses are ignored as a parameters and generated file is fixed.
Whole solution

```
  /* 
    #swagger.auto = false
    #swagger.tags = ['Diary']
    #swagger.description = 'Get all Diary entries'
    #swagger.parameters['date'] = {
      in: 'query',
      description: 'Date of diary entry',
      required: false,
    }
    #swagger.responses[200] = {
      description: 'Diary entries successfully obtained',
      schema: { $ref: '#/definitions/DiaryResponse'}
    }
  */
```